# Magento Paypal Express Error

Tags: multistore, paypal-express

I am looking for help in fixing a problem we have been having with our Magento for a while now

This is what has been happening: 
A customer will come to the website and use a coupon code during checkout. When they are paying they can choose between Paypal or Credit card. Both options are going through Paypal anyways using “Website Payments Pro”. Right before the customer confirms the payment they see an error like this “PayPal gateway has rejected request. A successful transaction has already been completed for this token (#10415: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).”

Then once that happens they are STILL getting charged through Paypal/Credit card. But an order is not being generated in Magento for our records and the customer is not receiving an order confirmation. If they keep clicking on Confirm Order then they will see this error each time while their card is getting billed each time.

Since there was no response to the question here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/c../viewthread/291770/ I copied it over to stackoverflow.

Comment: were you ever able to figure out what happened here?